# gradle runs xcodebuild at wrong directory

Tags: gradle, xcodebuild

I have few projects which builded by Gradle. Each project has its own build.gradle file.
I'm trying to write common build script like this:

```
task buildAndroid(type: GradleBuild) {
    buildFile = 'Android/build.gradle'
    tasks = ['buildAll']
}

task buildIOS(type: GradleBuild) {
    buildFile = 'iOS/build.gradle'
    tasks = ['debugBuild', 'releaseBuild']
}
```

Android build works correct, but iOS build doesn't: xcodebuild runs in common project directory, not in iOS subdir:

```
xcodebuild: error: The directory /path/to/common/project/dir does not contain an Xcode project.
```

Please advice me how to build iOS project in correct way.

Comment: What plugin do you use for ios building?